# Pass IDs on the basis of selected drop down item in angular4

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular-forms

I am working on Angular 4 Web API I want to like, when selecting a PackingTypeName automatically pass their id to API. which means when selecting a packing type Name and press add button the selected Name and its ID can be saved to DB. actually, I am new in angular. can anyone help please its a big help form me

```html
<select class="form-control"id="PackingtypeName" placeholder="name" name="PackingtypeName" #PackingtypeName="ngModel" ngModel>                               
   <option value="0" disabled>Please Select Packing type </option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of products" value={{item.PackingTypeID}}>{{item.PackingtypeName}}</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Add Item" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addItems(newStockoutForm.value);" />
```

This is my TS file

```js
    addItems(value: any) {
        this.items = new IComboDetails( value.PackingTypeID,value.PackingtypeName);     
        alert(value.PackingtypeName); //when showing alert packing type name is undefined
        alert(value.PackingTypeID);
        this.stockitems.push(this.items);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The option value is `item.PackingTypeID` not item, if you alert value in `addItems` function it will print your selected item's id, not the whole item object. If you want to get the product's name you should filter products array.

```
addItems(value: any) {
   console.log(value); //prints selected product's PackingTypeID
   let PackingtypeName = this.products.filter(it => it.PackingTypeID == value)[0].PackingtypeName;
   console.log(PackingtypeName ); //prints selected product's PackingtypeName 
   this.items = new IComboDetails( value, PackingtypeName);
   this.stockitems.push(this.items);
}
```

Comment: actually, i am not using the filter concept(i dont know that ) got an error filter does not exixt on the type IcomboDetails

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control"id="PackingtypeName" placeholder="name" name="PackingtypeName" #PackingtypeName="ngModel" ngModel>                               
   <option value="0" disabled>Please Select Packing type </option>
    <option *ngFor="let item of products" value={{item.PackingTypeID}}>{{item.PackingtypeName}}</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Add Item" class="btn btn-success" (click)="addItems(newStockoutForm.value);" />
```

in your ts file

```
export class AppComponent {
  selectedOption;     
  selectedOptionOnbuttonClick;
  selectedIdOnbuttonClick;


  addItems() {
    this.selectedOptionOnbuttonClick= this.selectedOption.PackingtypeName;
    this.selectedIdOnbuttonClick = this.selectedOption.PackingTypeID;
  }
}
```